# Adding values from select dropdown with javascript

Tags: javascript

I am creating a form that has select inputs and the values add up to a certain score. I can't get the values from the select to add and the sum into the total input to show the score of their test.

jscript:

```
function calculate_total(){
        var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('Assessment');
        var myLength = elems.length,
        total = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < myLength; ++i) {
          total += parseInt(elems[i].value * 1);
        }
        document.getElementById('ScoreTot').value = total;

}
```

html:

```
<cfselect name="SELECT1" id="select1" class="Assessment">
    <option value="0"> OPTION 1 </option>
    <option value="1"> OPTION 2 </option>
</cfselect>

<cfselect name="select2" id="select2" class="Assessment">
    <option value="0"> OPTION 1 </option>
    <option value="1"> OPTION 2 </option>
    <option value="2"> OPTION 3 </option>
</cfselect>

<cfselect name="select3" id="select3" class="Assessment">
    <option value="0"> OPTION 1 </option>
    <option value="1"> OPTION 2 </option>
    <option value="2"> OPTION 3 </option>
</cfselect>

Score: <cfinput type="text" name="ScoreTot" id="ScoreTot" value="">
```

Comment: What is `cfselect` ?

Comment: You also never call your `calculate_total` function

Comment: In addition to everything else, you should change your for loop increment from `++i` to `i++`

Answer (score 1):

With selects, you need to use the value of the option that is selected especially if you plan to serve older browsers.

`elems[i].options[elems[i].selectedIndex].value`

And, as another answer points out, parseInt should have a radix.

```
 function calculate_total(){
    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('Assessment');
    var myLength = elems.length,
    total = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < myLength; ++i) {
      total += parseInt(elems[i].options[elems[i].selectedIndex].value * 1,10);
    }
    document.getElementById('ScoreTot').value = total;
}
```

Comment: This solution worked. I had no idea select values were handled differently, thanks.

Comment: In modern browsers, the `value` on a select list itself will reflect the selected option's value.

Comment: Agreed, it's on paper that `.value` works in ie7+, but I've found it to be unreliable even in modern browsers.  a few more keystrokes ensures it works.  The MDN states that it will work with .value, but in the example given, also uses the selectedIndex method:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement

Answer (score 1):

There are some errors in your logic. Below is a working copy, but first a few notes:

1. You've got ColdFusion HTML here or something, HTML does not by itself know was a `<cfselect>` or `<cfinput>` is, so this example shows valid HTML.
2. You're not calling your function anywhere. Make sure you do!

```js
function calculate_total() {
    var els = document.getElementsByClassName('Assessment'); 
    // always use var to declare variables in scope; they are global otherwise
    var total1 = 0;

    // Little benefit to storing the length elsewhere
    // Use i++ instead of ++i
    for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
        // Use a radix to indicate base 10, I didn't see a need for the *1
        total1 += parseInt(els[i].value, 10);
    }
    document.getElementById('ScoreTot').value = total1;

}

// Call your function somehow!
calculate_total();
```

```html
<select name="SELECT1" id="select1" class="Assessment">
    <option value="0">OPTION 1</option>
    <option value="1" selected>OPTION 2</option>
</select>
<select name="select2" id="select2" class="Assessment">
    <option value="0">OPTION 1</option>
    <option value="1">OPTION 2</option>
    <option value="2" selected>OPTION 3</option>
</select>
<select name="select3" id="select3" class="Assessment">
    <option value="0">OPTION 1</option>
    <option value="1">OPTION 2</option>
    <option value="2" selected>OPTION 3</option>
</select>Score:
<input type="text" name="ScoreTot" id="ScoreTot" value="">
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 parseInt( number, 10)
```

parseInt needs a radix

Answer (score 0):

Here it is not clear when you want the function to be executed.
Add a button to the dom and attach an event to it.

```js
var e = document.getElementById('foo');
e.onclick = calculateTotal;

function calculateTotal(){
    
        var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('Assessment');
        var myLength = elems.length,
        total = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < myLength; ++i) {
          total += parseInt(elems[i].value * 1);
        }
        document.getElementById('ScoreTot').value = total;

}
```

```html
<select name="SELECT1" id="select1" class="Assessment">
    <option value="0"> OPTION 1 </option>
    <option value="1"> OPTION 2 </option>
</select>

<select name="select2" id="select2" class="Assessment">
    <option value="0"> OPTION 1 </option>
    <option value="1"> OPTION 2 </option>
    <option value="2"> OPTION 3 </option>
</select>

<select name="select3" id="select3" class="Assessment">
    <option value="0"> OPTION 1 </option>
    <option value="1"> OPTION 2 </option>
    <option value="2"> OPTION 3 </option>
</select>

Score: <input type="text" name="ScoreTot" id="ScoreTot" value="">

<input type="button" id="foo" value="Add" />
```

Here is the working example
https://jsfiddle.net/u3sj6euy/